# SQLite insert command not works

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert

I don't understand why this insert statement not works. The debugging works fine and it returns "true". When I test it by SQLite Studio it works also.
(The ID is an integer and auto increments.) There are no errors.

```
public bool InsertInDB(string tForm, string tLang, string tKey, string tValue)
        {
            SqliteCommand cmd;
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tForm)) { throw new NullReferenceException("Missing: tForm"); }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tLang)) { throw new NullReferenceException("Missing: tLang"); }
                string[] temp = tLang.Split('-');
                if (temp.Length != 2) { throw new Exception("The language description is wrong. Form \"xx-xx\", ex.: \"en-US\""); }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tKey)) { throw new NullReferenceException("Missing: tKey"); }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tValue)) { throw new NullReferenceException("Missing: tValue"); }

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tForm", tForm);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tLang", tLang);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tKey", tKey);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tValue", tValue);
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Translate (Form, Lang, Key, Value) VALUES (@tForm, @tLang, @tKey, @tValue)";
                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Open(); }
                var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return (result > 0);
            }
            catch (SqliteException ex)
            {
                HandleException(ex, "InsertInDB");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleException(ex, "InsertInDB");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: There are no errors. It works fine.